# Jquery Hide Show ScrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, mousehover

i am looking for a way to show the children of my div when i scroll down .

Here my code :

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    var test = 0;
    $('#one').children('div').hide().css({
        'overflow': 'hidden'
    });

    $('#one').hover(function () {
        $(this).children('div').stop(true, true).show('slow');
    }, function () {
        $(this).children('div').stop(true, true).hide('slow');
    });
```

When i scroll down like two time ( ~ 30 pix) , i want to show the div children so when the user reach again the top of his screen he can see the div children but this:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >11) {
        test+=1;
    }

if(test!==0){
    $('#one').children('div').show().css({
       'overflow': 'visible'
    });
```

seems not to work. I want this trick to work without modify the mousehoverfunction.

[here the jsfiddle for better understanding](http://jsfiddle.net/DatKebab/448mj/55/).

Comment: Thanks Spokey for the Edit.

Comment: I didnt understood this part  $('#one').children('div').show().css({
       'overflow': 'visible'
    }); what you meant to do

Comment: What i want to do actually is to  keep the div children as visible when the user start to scroll. I just want the user to see this : -open the page, div children hidden, use mouse hover , children appears/disapears, scroll a bit down to see content, scroll again to top and reach top of screen , see children as visible, use mousehover , LOOP . I hope its kinda clear now :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/448mj/70/)**

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function (e) {
    var test = 0;
    $('#one').children('div').hide().css({
        'overflow': 'hidden'
    });
    $('#one').hover(function () {

        $(this).children('div').stop(true, true).show('slow');
    }, function () {
        $(this).children('div').stop(true, true).hide('slow');
    });

});
$(window).scroll(function(event) {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >11) {
     $('#one').children('div').stop(true,true).show();
    }

});
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: It kinda helps but there a lil misunderstanding i guess. I dont want to keep the children visible for the user while scrolling. I just want them to be "unwraped" like the mousehover effect i did at the begining but without using the mouse. In short, i simply want the "children.show" effect to be done when you reach scrollTop>11. Thanks for the help anw :) .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It helps a lot actually. I just need one tip/advice. I want to make the same annimation effect as the beggining. I want the same children.show effect when you reach the top. I dunno if i can do that actually but thanks for the help dude :).

Comment: You are welcome check this out ,I guess this is what you need http://jsfiddle.net/448mj/73/

Comment: hum. That's not the idea. Keep the children hidden at the begining and then when you scroll down to , lets say 100pix , and you reach the top again, the same show animation as the mousehover will be triggered, like the facebook android application for example(the menu will  wrapped down when you reach top of the screen). I'm working on it actually :).